# videoview right side white space

Tags: android, android-videoview

i can't remove the white space of my video preview i already added all the alignparent but still dont work. it's source is from a server. the video has no white space in it.

here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.extras.PermitVideoFrag">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vid_permit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

its really frustrating me now. i can't find a decent answer.

Comment: Please share reference screen for videoview.

Comment: add screenshot too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an answer. I used DisplayMetrics to measure the fragment's dimension then set it as the dimension of the videopreview:

```
vid_permit = (VideoView)permit.findViewById(R.id.vid_permit);
vid_permit.setVideoURI(vidUri);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
vid_permit.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));

vid_permit.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to used below xml for video view and remove unnecessary xml tag like layout_centerHorizontal,layout_alignParentStart.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoViewRelative"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck at this for more than 3 hrs, finally realised that its all about the resizing of video. I was trying to add videoview of a specific fixed height to my layout and then I got this issue. all it took is setting,

```
layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to videoview and the white space dissapeared.